# Azure Service Bus SAS acces through AZURE JAVA SDK

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-java-sdk

We are creating a project that uses SAS authorization for Azure Service Bus, we can properly use that authentication method through .NET api, the problem comes when trying to access through the Azure Java SDK.

After some research the dev team from Azure Java SDK said about a year ago that SAS support for service bus would be added, but after a year there's no official support for it. Is there any workaround or third party libraries I can use to access my service bus queues through SAS authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use ACS, but the service bus namespace needs to be created via the PowerShell cmdlet new-azuresbnamespace.

As for using the SAS signature, the only real difference between ACS and SAS is the contents of the "Authorization" http header on the request. If you can dig into the SDK you're using, it should hopefully be a simple matter to make it use a SAS value for this header.